# How to intercept and change http requests with c#

Tags: c#, http, interceptor

is it possible to intercept when an app is making an http get request to a server?

I need to intercept when some websites are opened and add some custom http headers in the request.

The app will work as a monitor in the system tray...

I'm using c#. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Fiddler Core](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/)

> FiddlerCore allows you to integrate HTTP/HTTPS traffic viewing and
>   modification capabilities into your .NET application, without any of
>   the Fiddler UI.